# Fat geometry shader

Tags: shaders, geometry

I've seen [this video](http://vimeo.com/17073934): all the geometry seems to grow and become fat. Nice effect.

I'm just approaching the shader matter, and I'm still have to learn a lot about how to change geometry via shaders. Where can I find dome information or similar example to replicate this effect?

Comment: Isn't it just moving vertices along it's normal in vertex shader?

Comment: It is. What gives this a distinct style is that he uses kinect's data and constructs the measured scene by spheres. Make the spheres bigger (translate vertices along their normals) and you're done.

Comment: @JozefCulen : can you link me an example please?